# Unable to POST to a specific route in my app

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

### Hey everyone!

So, I've been following along a project, in which I'm developing a simple app that I register products in, and they go to my mongodb database. Handlebars as the templating engine.

Problem is, I keep getting the same `Cannot POST /products/create` every time I try to make a post request with the new product. Also getting 404 status.

Here's some of my code:

#### // `index.js`

```
const express = require("express");
const exphbs = require("express-handlebars");
const app = express();

const conn = require("./db/conn");

const productsRoutes = require("./routes/productsRoutes");

app.engine("handlebars", exphbs.engine());

app.set("view engine", "handlebars");

app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    extended: true,
  })
);

app.use(express.json());

app.use("/products", productsRoutes);

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.listen(3000);
```

#### // `productRoutes.js`

```
const express = require("express");

const router = express.Router();

const ProductController = require("../controllers/ProductController");

router.get("/create", ProductController.createProduct);
router.post("/create,", ProductController.createProductPost);
router.get("/", ProductController.showProducts);

module.exports = router;
```

#### // `ProductController.js`

```
const Product = require("../models/Product");

module.exports = class ProductController {
  static showProducts(req, res) {
    res.render("products/all");
  }
  static createProduct(req, res) {
    res.render("products/create");
  }
  static createProductPost(req, res) {
    const { name, price, description } = req.body;

    const product = new Product(name, price, description);

    product.save();

    res.redirect("products");
  }
};
```

#### // also, the template `create.handlebars` if it helps

```
<h1>Create product</h1>
<form action="/products/create" method="post">
    <div class="form-control">
        <label for="name">Nome do produto:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Digite o nome do produto">
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
        <label for="price">Preço do produto:</label>
        <input type="number" name="price" placeholder="Digite o preço">
    </div>
    <div class="form-control">
        <label for="description">Descrição do produto:</label>
        <textarea name="description" placeholder="Descrição do produto"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Enviar"/>
</form>
```

Tried to make a post request to my database, and received `cannot post` error.

Comment: You seem to have a mistype here `router.post("/create,"...)`

Comment: i think the problem in the `index.js`. `const productsRoutes = require("./routes/productsRoutes")` in your description its `productRoutes` without `s`. cmiiw